# Can the phrase "air pocket" be used figuratively?

Tags: usage, phrases

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

With its most ordered plane's fate undecided, Boeing may well be heading towards an air pocket.

Merriam Webster dictionaries define "air pocket" as a movement or condition of the air that causes an airplane to make a brief and sudden downward drop

I don't think the phrase has been used here in the literal sense.

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the author of  "The Hindu" to find out exactly what they meant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely treating Boeing metaphorically, as if it were an aeroplane - and what is about to happen to it may be what happens to the planes it makes if they hit an air pocket. Some journalists love that sort of casual, topical, 'appropriate' metaphor.